# Smart table filter with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want live filter, using jQuery, in my table.

For example: I want to show only rows where name column contains "a" and column freelancer select input is setted to "yes".

I found some solutions that is filtering fulltextly based on text-inputs, and some solutions which are based on select-inputs, but nothing where is combination of both. Is there some way how to do it without data tables or similar plugins?

I will appreciate for every tips!

```html
<table id="testTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name <input type="text" name="name"></th>
            <th>Surname <input type="text" name="surname" /></th>
            <th>City <select name="city">
                        <option value="NY">NY</option>
                        <option value="NJ">NJ</option>
                     </select>       
            </th>
            <th>Freelancer <select name="freelancer">
                                <option value="yes">yes</option>
                                <option value="no">no</option>
                            </select>  
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>John</td><td>Smith</td><td>NJ</td><td>yes</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Luke</td><td>Jones</td><td>NY</td><td>no</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Jack</td><td>White</td><td>NY</td><td>yes</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Abby</td><td>Scott</td><td>NJ</td><td>yes</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Luke</td><td>Price</td><td>NY</td><td>no</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: did you try anything ?

Answer (score 0):

here is a small code pen working for your first column, basically I am just retrieving the vlaue of the input everytime the user type a new letter and I am going throught all the array and checking if the name contains the input.

First you need to add an id to your input:

```
id="name" // just an example
```

and i added a classname to your first td :

```
class="name"
```

Then you can add the method in you js file

```
$('#name').keyup(function () {
  var tr = $('.name')
  var input = $('#name').val()
  tr.each(function() {
    console.log($(this).html().indexOf(input))
    if($(this).html().indexOf(input) >= 0){
      $(this).parent().show()
    }
    else{
      $(this).parent().hide()      
    }
  })
})
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dmrKxm

I hope it will help you